# Parallelly execute tasks on x instances

Tags: linux, bash

I need to execute a dataset processing task. It’s a simple php script to warm up memcached machines. The dataset contains the keys (around 24 million)

If I were to execute the warm up script from one machine it will take me nearly 3 days to complete. But if I were to “split” and run 6 differences process it will take me a day.

If I know the ip address of all the other machines in my network and has ssh access, is there a way to parallelize this task?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [pssh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/), [cluster ssh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/), ...

1. setting up ssh public key authentication
2. creating a list of your machine:

   ```
   ip1:port1 user1
   ip2:port2 user2
   ip3:port3 user3
   ```
3. distributing your script to all the servers and parallelize:

   ```
   $ pssh -h <host_file> -P /path/to/php/script
   ```